# Could not find Maintenance.flag file in root folder magento

Tags: magento

I was trying to install an extension in my magento site which was failed in the middle later i could not get access to my admin neither to my site as it shows this error.

http://prntscr.com/68qc3c

this error should be removed maintenance.flag file but this file is not available in my root folder. Please assist me if there is any other way possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `maintenance.flag` file *must* still be in your root directory, otherwise Magento would not be displaying the 503 error. The way that this is displayed is a result of the `index.php` file, around line 66:

```
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) { 
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

This page cannot even be cached. Re-connect to your FTP server and check for the file in your html directory on the webserver. Alternately, speak with your web hosts & have them remove the file.

As a precaution, you can try deleting your var/cache directory and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

two possible ways are

1 . you can delete manually both *session* and *cache* directory from var directory.

path

```
magento_root/var/
```

2. or you can delete all files of that extension and reinstall again.